# Double 'at' symbol meaning in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I know that `@` symbol followed by a path means executing that script in PL/SQL. What does `@@` followed by a path mean?

Comment: There is no `@@` in PL/SQL. PL/SQL is the language used **only** for stored procedures in Oracle. `@` and `@@` are commands for `SQL*Plus` they are defintiely not PL/SQL and they are not even SQL commands.

Answer (score 5):

```
@@{url | file_name[.ext] } [arg...]
```

> Runs a script. This command is almost identical to the @ ("at" sign)
>   command. When running nested scripts it looks for nested scripts in
>   the same path or url as the calling script. Only the url form is
>   supported in iSQL*Plus. The @@ command functions similarly to @ and
>   START.

Ref :http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12003.htm